# remove values from array except defined range

Tags: javascript

I want date range from 12 to 15. How to get this? Please help

```
let dates = ["10/07/2021", "11/07/2021", "12/07/2021", "13/07/2021", "14/07/2021", "15/07/2021", "16/07/2021", "17/07/2021"];
```

Remove item before 12 and after 15

```
newDates = ["12/07/2021", "13/07/2021", "14/07/2021", "15/07/2021"];
```

Comment: use array filter method for this - like `let newDates = dates.filter(date => checkDate(date))` where all you have to do is write the `checkDate` function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alternatively (this is essentially @Bravo's suggestion in the comments / @Nithleh's answer below but using regex to make the code a little cleaner):

```
dates = dates.filter( date => {
let d = new Date(date.replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, '$3-$2-$1'))
   return d.getDate() >= 12 && d.getDate() <= 15
} )
// shoud return ["12/07/2021", "13/07/2021", "14/07/2021", "15/07/2021"]
```

---

Regex explanation:

`\d` matches single digits 0-9 (and other numerical digits). `{2}` specifies the length of the matching set. `(..)` captures groups and `\/` matches the `/`.

Your date format is `12/07/2021`. In other words, a group of 2 digits followed by a forward slash `/` followed by a group of 2 digits followed by a `/` followed by a group of 4 digits. This translates into:
`(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})`. This captures 3 parts; first part 2 digits (`$1`), second part 2 digits (`$2`) and the third part 4 digits (`$3`).

Replace function takes care of formatting the date into yyyy-mm-dd format since `Date` requires the date string to be in that format.

Now we know that the third part `$3` holds year, `$2` month and `$1` day. So `date.replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, '$3-$2-$1')` replaces (shifts the parts) the original date `12/07/2021` with the newly formatted date `2021/07/12`

---

Now `let d = new Date(date.replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, '$3-$2-$1'))` will have a date object and `d.getDate()` will give the day portion.

Note that this solution `d.getDate() >= 12 && d.getDate() <= 15` would only work if the dates fall within the same month of the same year OR if you want to get these particular days regardless of the month or year.